# Justify-left at linebreak for EditText?

Tags: android

I have a EditText, where the text is in the middle of the EditText(gravity:center)
But when a line break happens, the text starts from the middle under the text. What I want is that the text shall start from the left when a linebreak happens.

This picture explains what I want to archive: http://oi61.tinypic.com/zycxut.jpg

I have tried all theese: Text-align:Viewstart/textStart, Gravity: Center | left
without any succses.

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edittext"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="320dp"
    android:editable="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
    android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
    android:singleLine="false"
    android:gravity="center"/>
```

Comment: any code to show what you are doing?

Comment: Yes @ergonaut and here is a picture that explain what I want: oi61.tinypic.com/zycxut.jpg

Comment: It looks like you want the text to be left justified, but each line starts at the (horizontal) middle of the field?

Comment: @BrettHaines Correct. Look at this picture:  oi61.tinypic.com/zycxut.jpg
I want my Edittext to behave like "left start" picture in the link

Comment: @BrettHaines take a look at the picture

Comment: @Elshaw I tried to answer your question, let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

you can add `android:inputType="textMultiLine"`

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/edittext"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="320dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:editable="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:textColor="#000000" />
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, so by the looks of your picture, it seems that you want the text left justified and starting in the middle of the `EditText`.  There isn't a way to do this directly, but we can make a work around by using 2 `EditText`s, each taking up half of the white block in your image, then ignoring the one on the left.  This will give the appearance of text starting from the middle, when in reality it starts from the left edge of the right `EditText`.

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="320dp"
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/ignore_this_one"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:editable="false" />
    <EditText 
        android:id="@+id/put_text_in_here"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"  
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:editable="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:textColor="#000000" />
</LinearLayout>
```

First, notice how each `EditText` has a `layout_weight` of 1.  This tells Android that they should each take up an equal amount of space on the screen, making them each take up half.

Second, notice how the second `EditText` has a `gravity_vertical` element.  This makes it so text is centered vertically, but not horizontally.

Comment: Hi. Sorry for the delay. I totally forgot about it, while working on a another project. This is not a good solution for me because I'm searching for a programmable/dynamic solution. I may have found a answer to how, so I will post it here.